# Constraints are not working as expected in landscape orientation

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout, orientation, constraints

I test very simple layout with autolayout use storyboard only(no code any where)

i dropped the Button object wAny, hAny and then switch size class to wCompact, hAny

and add Constraint 'Center Horizontally in Container' & 'Top Space to Top layout guide'.

next i switch size class to wAny, hCompact and add constraint 'Center Vertically in Container' & 'Trailling space to Container Margin' and width,height constraint

that's all i added constraints, there is no warning and error in storyboard.

i expected as top centered button in portrait and right centered in landscape.

portrait is running normally but preview and simulator show me wrong result when i was change orientation with error log.

like this

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "\<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7a065db0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7a067440(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7a068010 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7a067440]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7a0661d0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a0680b0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7a067440]-(20)-[UIButton:0x7a066740'Button']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a06d9e0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x7a0661d0(320)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a068050 UIView:0x7a0661d0.centerY == UIButton:0x7a066740'Button'.centerY>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a0680e0 V:[UIButton:0x7a066740'Button'(30)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a0680e0 V:[UIButton:0x7a066740'Button'(30)]>
```

and button fills width and height its container view.

i can't figure out what i did wrong?

am i missing something important about autolayout(with orientation)?

plz help me

(sorry for my bad english. i'm non english native speaker-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that **wCompact|hAny** is for iPhones in portrait or landscape.  So you end up with conflicting constraints in landscape because all of your constraints apply.  You should use **wCompact|hRegular** for iPhones in portrait.

Comment: thank you for your concern, i think wCompact|hAny means portrait base value because its grid style looks like.

Comment: When you select wCompact|hAny, read the description that is there. It tells you it is for iPhones in Portrait or Landscape. I followed your directions and when I used wCompact|hAny I had the same conflicts that you have. When I used wCompact|hRegular, there were no conflicts. Try it.